# SQL conversion from varchar to uniqueidentifier fails in view

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-2012

I'm stuck on the following scenario. 
I have a database with a table with customer data and a table where I put records for monitoring what is happening on our B2B site.

The customer table is as follow:

- ID, int, not null
- GUID, uniqueidentfier, not null, primary key
- Other stuff...

The monitoring table:

- ID, int, not null
- USERGUID, uniqueidentifier, null
- PARAMETER2, varchar(50), null
- Other stuff...

In PARAMETER1 are customer guids as wel as other data types stored.

Now the question came to order our customers according their last visit date, the most recent visited customers must come on the top of a grid.

I'm using Entity Framework and I had problems of comparing the string and the guid type, so I decided to make a view on top of my monitoring table:

```
SELECT        
   ID, 
   CONVERT(uniqueidentifier, parameter2) AS customerguid, 
   USERguid, 
   CreationDate
FROM            
   MONITORING
WHERE        
   (dbo.isuniqueidentifier(parameter2) = 1) 
   AND 
   (parameter1 LIKE 'Customers_%' OR parameter1 LIKE 'Customer_%')
```

I imported the view in EF and made my Linq query. It returned nothing, so I extracted the generated SQL query. When testing the query in SQL Management Studio I got the following error:
**Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.**

The problem lies in the following snippet (simplified for this question, but also gives an error:

```
SELECT *,
    (
        SELECT 
            [v_LastViewDateCustomer].[customerguid] AS [customerguid]
        FROM [dbo].[v_LastViewDateCustomer] AS [v_LastViewDateCustomer]
        WHERE c.GUID = [v_LastViewDateCustomer].[customerguid]
    )

FROM CM_CUSTOMER c
```

But when I do a join, I get my results:

```
SELECT *
FROM CM_CUSTOMER c
    LEFT JOIN
    [v_LastViewDateCustomer] v
on c.GUID = v.customerguid
```

I tried to make a SQL fiddle, but it is working on that site. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/66d68/3

Anyone who can point me in the right direction?

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use

```
TRY_CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, parameter2) AS customerguid
```

instead of

```
 CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, parameter2) AS customerguid
```

Views are inlined into the query and the `CONVERT` can run before the `WHERE`.

For some additional discussion see [SQL Server should not raise illogical errors](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/537419/sql-server-should-not-raise-illogical-errors)

Comment: Will try that, but compatibility level is set to SQL Server 2005 apparently. I've asked the system admin to change that.

Comment: @JurgenStillaert - Well assuming your `dbo.isuniqueidentifier` function works correctly then you can do `CASE WHEN dbo.isuniqueidentifier(parameter2) = 1 THEN CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, parameter2) END AS customerguid` instead.

Comment: Both solutions work. But very slow (40 seconds to get 10 customers), so I still have some work to do.